# Passing variable in XML topology in ODI

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I am trying to parameterized the topology connection in ODI to load multiple xml of same structure one by one using variable.But i am getting unknown token error.

**Jdbc url :jdbc:snps:xml?f=U:/SOTI_CLOUD/#B.xml**

{ #B is ODI variable having file name)

Answer (score 0):

Try using #GLOBAL.B if it is a Global variable or #<PROJECT_NAME>.B if it is a project variable.

Also check what is your history setting for that variable. If it is set on "No History", make sure you are declaring/refreshing the variable within the same session in which you want to access that XML file.

Comment: Thanks, But it didnt work out. I tried using global and project variable as well.I am also refreshing variables before using in the topology. 
Ex 1:  jdbc:snps:xml?f=U:/SOTI_CLOUD/#GLOBAL.PP.xml
       

Ex 2: jdbc:snps:xml?f=U:/SOTI_CLOUD/#PRJGSSP_SOTI_DEVICE_MANAGEMENT.PP.xml

Comment: Could you run it with log level set to 6? Is you variable populated correctly?
You might also need to surround it by single quotes to have it interpreted as text.

Comment: by putting it in single quotes, it is treating it as a string and taking  considering #PRJGSSP_SOTI_DEVICE_MANAGEMENT.PP as fie name, Not the value of variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch…

For the variable to be picked up in JDBC URL you need to launch a separate scenario. Your problem might be different but make sure you have an outer loop with variable declare/refresh and whenever you refresh/increment it you launch a separate scenario (not just an interface) where you load data using such constructed URL.

Comment: Thanks.I tried this way and now not getting token error.But still getting error for invalid schema name.I am passing variable to physical schema also.

JDBC URL: jdbc:snps:xml?f=/u02/home/odiftp/odiprojects/motsoti/fromsoti/#PRJGSSP_SOTI_DEVICE_MANAGEMENT.SOTI_DEVICE_FILE_NAME.xml&d=/u02/home/odiftp/odiprojects/motsoti/fromsoti/#PRJGSSP_SOTI_DEVICE_MANAGEMENT.SOTI_DEVICE_FILE_NAME.dtd&s=#PRJGSSP_SOTI_DEVICE_MANAGEMENT.SOTI_DEVICE_FILE_NAME&ro=false


Schema(Schema): #PRJGSSP_SOTI_DEVICE_MANAGEMENT.SOTI_DEVICE_FILE_NAME

Schema(Work Schema): #PRJGSSP_SOTI_DEVICE_MANAGEMENT.SOTI_DEVICE_FILE_NAME

Comment: I would strongly advice to always use one XML schema (as reversed from XSD or DTD) per one XML physical schema. In my experience anything else won't work (or don't make much sense).

Comment: You mean to say it is not possible to load multiple xml files with different name but same structure in a loop in a ODI ? We are passing variable name in schema because each file is associated with one schema only.

Comment: Wouldn't it work with the dod (drop on disconnect) argument set to true? So the schema would be rebuilt for every XML file.
I would try hardcoding the schema name though.

Comment: My point is - If you have same structure - why do you pass (XML) schema name in variable?